# Using strftime on a django datetime produces a UTC time in the string

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following code in one of my models:

```
def shortDescription(self):
    return self.name + ' ' + self.class_date.strftime("%I:%M")
```

`self.class_date` is a timezone aware `DateTimeField`, `self.class_date.is_aware()` is `True`, `USE_TZ` is `True`.

The shortDescription returns a string that gives the time in UTC rather than the default timezone,  putting `{{ aclass.class_date }}` in the template displays the time in the correct zone.

Is `strftime` always working on the base, native time? Or what else is going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by "timezone aware date"? What class is it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you directly reference pieces of the datetime like `%I` or `%M`, it uses it straight as it is with no locale conversion. If you included `%Z` you'd see that the time is in `UTC`. If you want locale-aware results, you need use the more limited `%X`, which will simply spit out the full time converted for the locale.

If you need more, you'll have to convert it:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def shortDescription(self):
    class_date = timezone.localtime(self.class_date)
    return self.name + ' ' + class_date.strftime("%I:%M")
```

Or, you can rely on the `date` filter, which automatically does this for you:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters

def shortDescription(self):
    return self.name + ' ' + defaultfilters.date(self.class_date, 'g:i')
```

Comment: Excellent.  And I didn't know about the defaultfilters trick at all.

Comment: Yeah, I use it all the time. Django template filters are just regular methods, so you can use any of them anywhere in your code. `defaultfilters.slugify` comes in handy quite often as well.

Comment: Does not work for me, [same Problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050530/django-defaultfilters-date-not-timezone-aware)

Comment: The first approach worked better. Thank you for the solution. :)

Comment: `class_date` needs to be converted to local time in the second approach too.