# Django defaultfilters.date not timezone aware

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-filter, django-timezone

Im trying to create a definition for django admin list_display, but the date filter is not timezone aware. If I just have the `updated_date` field in list_display, the time is correct.

```
def get_edited_by(self):
    return u"%s %s - %s" % (self.edited_by.first_name, self.edited_by.last_name,
           defaultfilters.date(self.updated_date, 'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT'))
```

The output is: `Bob Bobson - 26.02.2014 18:27` (one hour off)

The output from just the `updated_date` is: `26. februar 2014 19:27` (correct)

Anyone know how to make `defaultfilters.date` timezone aware?

## Edit:

My settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Oslo'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

## Edit2:

`pytz==2013.9`
`Django==1.6.2`

## Edit 3:

Tried this

```
from django.utils.dateformat import DateFormat
def get_edited_by(self):
    return u"%s %s - %s" % (self.edited_by.first_name, self.edited_by.last_name, DateFormat.format(self.updated_date, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT"))
```

But I get this error: `unbound method format() must be called with DateFormat instance as first argument (got datetime instance instead)`

## Edit 4:

```
from django.utils import date format
def get_edited_by(self):
    return u"%s %s - %s" % (self.edited_by.first_name, self.edited_by.last_name, dateformat.format(self.updated_date, 'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT'))
```

Gives this output: `Bob Bobsen - th23+0100RCET_onsPMCETFebruarCET0FebFebruar_februar+0100RFebPMCET`

Comment: Is [`USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz) set?

Comment: Yes, updated question with settings

Comment: do you have pytz installed?

Comment: Yes, pytz is installed.

Comment: What happens if you *disable* timezone support? I know that's counter-intuitive, but I had tons of troubles with it myself with one of my projects, and not using it turned out to be the answer

Comment: If I set `USE_TZ = False` it seems to work. But is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: For further debugging, use a format string that shows the time zone. I'm assuming that the wrong output is in UTC while the right one is Europe/Oslo. This might have something to do with using a filter in a non-template context. Try using `django.utils.dateformat.format(value, format_string)` instead.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: Tried it, but I got an error. Question updated.

Comment: It looks like `format_string` is expected to be an actual [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). If you want to use the format name as above, try `django.utils.formats.date_format(value, format)`.

Comment: `django.utils.formats.date_format(value, format)` display the string correct, but one hour off.

Comment: Same error, `USE_TZ = False` as @Garreth00 wrote does not work for me.